# Thinking in SOLID principle during the design process

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm new to SOLID principle and design, I understand the principle however, I have a hard time knowing where to start the design process. I understand that design is an iterative process, what step or question you ask yourself during the design process so your design conforms to SOLID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try test-driven development. In an object-oriented context, you'll typically have to explicitly consider both the [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), and the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in order to make your system under test testable and deterministic.

There are other ways to make APIs testable. If, for example, you're using functional programming, [pure functions are intrinsically testable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/07/functional-design-is-intrinsically-testable). In that case, you don't need to explicitly think about SOLID.